# Can I View the Filters Currently Enabled on an Azure ServiceBus Topic Subscription?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I'd like to let people change their subscription filters via an interface in my app. To do this, I need to show them which filters are currently applied to their subscription.

I cannot find anywhere in the documentation where it allows you to list the current filters.

You have the ability to `AddRule` and `RemoveRule`, but no way to list them. `RemoveRule` will even throw an exception if that rule already exists.

How can I determine which rules are currently being applied to my Topic Subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get list of rules for a specific topic and subscription through [`NamespaceManager.GetRules(string topicPath, string subscriptionName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh293119.aspx) :

```
        var rules = namespaceManager.GetRules("MyTopic", "MySubscriber");
        foreach (var ruleDescription in rules)
        {
            Console.Write(ruleDescription.Name);
            var filter = ruleDescription.Filter;
        }
```